# Indexed addressing mode

Tags: assembly, nasm, addressing-mode

I have been experimenting with different addressing modes and doing research on the subject; in my attempt to use indexed addressing mode, I borrowed pieces of code from different examples on SO.  In the example below:

```
outerLoop:
cmp edi, 50                  ;each element is 2 bytes (2 ascii characters)
ja  endloop                  ;we need 50 because it's 5 elements per row
mov esi, 0                   ;and 5 rows
innerLoop:
cmp esi, 5                   ;Compare esi(inner loop index) to 5
jae innerEnd                 ;jump if it reached the end of the row
mov ax, matrix[edi + esi*2]
cmp ax, cx
jg  biggerThan
mov cx, ax
```

The author is using a nested loop to parse through a 2-d array, and find the smallest number.
What I am really interested in, is(case 1):

```
mov ax, matrix[edi + esi*2]
```

As this part seems to cause a problem when compiling the code and it gives the error:
"comma, colon or end of line expected"
If I however change the code to(case 2):

```
[matrix + edi + esi*2]
```

Everything seems to be working fine.

Which one is the correct indexed addressing mode?
My intuition says that since "matrix" is the array, it should reside outside of the left bracket but that does not seem to be the case in practice.
I would appreciate if someone could explain the difference between case 1 and case 2.

Comment: I never use the first style personally, but some assemblers allow it and treat it the same as the second style. NASM, however, mandates that _"Everything in square brackets is a reference to a memory address, while everything outside of square brackets is a constant."_ ([source](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/wiki/NasmSyntax))

Comment: Different assemblers have different syntax rules.  Just use what works.

Comment: What is `matrix`? Is it the absolute 32-bit address from a .data or .bss section? Where did you get this code from?

Comment: @Zboson, Matrix is a 2-d array initialized as constants within .data